# CancellationToken Behavior

Tags: c#, .net, task, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I want to understand how the `CancellationToken` works, and how it cancels tasks.

For that, I created this example, which uses the same token for both the `Task.Run()` and the inner method - `HelpDoingSomething()`

So, I let the task run for 500ms, then I cancel the token, and the result is:

First printed message: *"HelpDoingSomething cancelled"* and then *"DoSomething cancelled"*

```csharp
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var myClass = new MyClass(cts.Token);
        myClass.DoSomething();

        Thread.Sleep(500);
        cts.Cancel();

        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

internal class MyClass
{
    private CancellationToken token;

    public MyClass(CancellationToken token)
    {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            HelpDoingSomething();
            System.Console.WriteLine("DoSomething cancelled");
        }, token);
    }

    private void HelpDoingSomething()
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            //Keep doing something
            System.Console.Write(".");
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("HelpDoingSomething cancelled");
    }
}
```

I know exactly that my method `HelpDoingSomething()` checks if the cancellationToken was requested on each iteration of the loop.

My question is how and how often does the `Task.Run()` method check if a cancellation token is requested?

Is that possible that `Task.Run()` will check that before `HelpDoingSomething()` does, and I will see only one message printed (*"DoSomething cancelled"*)? This means the logic may not be handled correctly in this method.

Comment: Since the cancellation needs to bubble "up" (to stop all subtasks) it's normal that the HelpDoingSomething cancelled is thrown before DoSomething cancelled is thrown, but you ask an entirely different question. What is your question? How often it's called, it's not a timely process, it's a whole different ballpark (in another country on a different continent) - Task.Run does not actively seek out cancellations, they get issued.

Comment: There is no chance you could see that output. The only way for `DoSomething cancelled` to appear is if `HelpDoingSomething cancelled` is also executed. If there is an exception before that then neither will appear. `Task.Run` doesn't check anything after the function has started, it's up to you to check the token then. It only checks it before starting the task

Comment: @riffnl, my question was not only "how often" but also "how". I wanted to understand how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cancellation token passed to `Task.Run()` is checked in two places:

(1) Before the task is actually started.

If the cancellation token is signalled before the task starts, the task will be placed into the "WaitingToRun" state quickly followed by the "Cancelled" state.

The action passed to the task will NOT be started in this case.

It may be possible to observe the "WaitingToRun" state if the task's state is checked very soon after calling `Task.Run()` but this is going to be a race condition and that state may not be observed. However, the "Cancelled" state will always eventually be set.

(2) When the action passed to the task throws `OperationCancelledException`.

As in case (1), the task will briefly transition to the "WaitingToRun" state which may be observable, but unlike case (1) this is quickly followed by the "Running" state (assuming that the cancellation token is cancelled AFTER the task has started).

If the token associated with the `OperationCancelledException` is the same as the one passed to `Task.Run()` the task will transition to the "Cancelled" state, otherwise it will transition to the "Faulted" state.

See here for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation

Here's a sample console app which demonstrates some of these cases:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test with already-cancelled token, but not passed to Task.Run()");
        CancellationTokenSource alreadyCancelled = new CancellationTokenSource();
        alreadyCancelled.Cancel();

        Task test1 = Task.Run(() => Test(alreadyCancelled.Token));

        Console.WriteLine("test1 status: " + test1.Status); // Probably "WaitingToRun", but this has a race condition.
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine("test1 status: " + test1.Status); // Certainly "Faulted".

        Console.WriteLine("\nTest with already-cancelled token passed to Task.Run()");
        Task test2 = Task.Run(() => Test(alreadyCancelled.Token), alreadyCancelled.Token);

        Console.WriteLine("test2 status: " + test2.Status); // Probably "WaitingToRun", but this has a race condition.
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine("test2 status: " + test2.Status); // Certainly "Cancelled".

        Console.WriteLine("\nTest with token cancelled after starting task, but not passed to Task.Run()");
        CancellationTokenSource cts3 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task test3 = Task.Run(() => Test(cts3.Token));

        Console.WriteLine("test3 status: " + test3.Status); // Probably "WaitingToRun", but this has a race condition.
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine("test3 status: " + test3.Status); // Certainly "Running".

        cts3.Cancel();
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine("test3 status: " + test3.Status); // Certainly "Faulted".

        Console.WriteLine("\nTest with token cancelled after starting task passed to Task.Run()");
        CancellationTokenSource cts4 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task test4 = Task.Run(() => Test(cts4.Token), cts4.Token);

        Console.WriteLine("test4 status: " + test4.Status); // Probably "WaitingToRun", but this has a race condition.
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine("test4 status: " + test4.Status); // Certainly "Running".

        cts4.Cancel();
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine("test4 status: " + test4.Status); // Certainly "Cancelled".

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Test(CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entering Test()");
        cancellation.WaitHandle.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("Cancellation detected");
        cancellation.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}
```

(It's a little bit of a lie where it says "Certainly" in the comments, but in normal circumstances 200ms should be far more than enough to observe the transition to that state. If you do not, increase the timeout. This is NOT something to do in production code!)

The output from this is:

```
Test with already-cancelled token, but not passed to Task.Run()
test1 status: WaitingToRun
Entering Test()
Cancellation detected
test1 status: Faulted

Test with already-cancelled token passed to Task.Run()
test2 status: WaitingToRun
test2 status: Canceled

Test with token cancelled after starting task, but not passed to Task.Run()
test3 status: WaitingToRun
Entering Test()
test3 status: Running
Cancellation detected
test3 status: Faulted

Test with token cancelled after starting task passed to Task.Run()
test4 status: WaitingToRun
Entering Test()
test4 status: Running
Cancellation detected
test4 status: Canceled
```

Note how for the second case "Test with already-cancelled token passed to Task.Run()", `Entering Test()` is not written to the console because the action is not called. This is the only test case where the action is not called at all.

Comment: Great example, thank you! There are still gaps in my knowledge that I need to close, but that makes more sense now.